# multiple Textboxes in curses

Tags: python, linux, curses

I need to create two Textboxes in curses and switch between them when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

this code put the cursor on the top-left corner of the screen when I press enter for the second Textbox and I can't prevent it.

```
import curses
import curses.textpad as textpad

def main(screen):
    """screen is a curses screen passed from the wrapper"""

    while True:
        event = screen.getch() 
        if event :
            textpad.Textbox(curses.newwin(1,13,4,0), insert_mode=True).edit()
            textpad.Textbox(curses.newwin(1,13,4,16), insert_mode=True).edit()
            screen.refresh()      

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't even need to call `getch()` as this is sufficient:

```
import curses
import curses.textpad as textpad

def main(screen):
    """screen is a curses screen passed from the wrapper"""
    while True:
        textpad.Textbox(curses.newwin(1,13,4,0), insert_mode=True).edit()
        textpad.Textbox(curses.newwin(1,13,4,16), insert_mode=True).edit()

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to press Enter a third time to get to the first Textbox, this is what I don't like

Comment: @metro, I updated my answer as modifying loop seem to work better.